# Propagation time of cancellation request to all tasks (TPL)

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation

With *TPL* we have `CancellationTokenSource` which provides tokens, useful to cooperatively cancellation of current task (or its start).

### Question:

How long it take to propagate cancellation request to all hooked running tasks?
Is there any place, where code could look to check that: "from now" every interested `Task`, will find that cancellation has been requested?

---

#### Why there is need for it?

I would like to have stable unit test, to show that cancellation works in our code.

#### Problem details:

We have "Executor" which produces tasks, these task wrap some long running actions. Main job of executor is to limit how many concurrent actions were started. All of these tasks can be cancelled individually, and also these actions will respect `CancellationToken` internally.

I would like to provide unit test, which shows that when cancellation occurred while task is waiting for *slot* to start *given action*, that task will cancel itself (eventually) and does not start execution of *given action*.

So, idea was to prepare `LimitingExecutor` with single *slot*. Then start *blocking action*, which would request cancellation when unblocked. Then "enqueue" *test action*, which should fail when executed. With that setup, tests would call *unblock* and then assert that task of *test action* will throw `TaskCanceledException` when awaited.

```
[Test]
public void RequestPropagationTest()
{
    using (var setupEvent = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false))
    using (var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource())
    using (var executor = new LimitingExecutor())
    {
        // System-state setup action:
        var cancellingTask = executor.Do(() =>
        {
            setupEvent.WaitOne();
            cancellation.Cancel();
        }, CancellationToken.None);

        // Main work action:
        var actionTask = executor.Do(() =>
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "This action should be cancelled!");
        }, cancellation.Token);

        // Let's wait until this `Task` starts, so it will got opportunity
        // to cancel itself, and expected later exception will not come
        // from just starting that action by `Task.Run` with token:
        while (actionTask.Status < TaskStatus.Running)
            Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: 1);

        // Let's unblock slot in Executor for the 'main work action'
        // by finalizing the 'system-state setup action' which will
        // finally request "global" cancellation:
        setupEvent.Set();

        Assert.DoesNotThrowAsync(
            async () => await cancellingTask);

        Assert.ThrowsAsync<TaskCanceledException>(
            async () => await actionTask);
    }
}

public class LimitingExecutor : IDisposable
{
    private const int UpperLimit = 1;
    private readonly Semaphore _semaphore
        = new Semaphore(UpperLimit, UpperLimit);

    public Task Do(Action work, CancellationToken token)
        => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _semaphore.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                work();
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }, token);

    public void Dispose()
        => _semaphore.Dispose();
}
```

Executable demo (via NUnit) of this problem could be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/DominikJaniec/JustProblems/tree/TaskCancellation/stability-problem/TaskCancellation/TaskCancellation).

However, implementation of that test sometimes fails (no expected `TaskCanceledException`), on my machin maybe 1 in 10 runs. Kind of "solution" to this problem is to insert `Thread.Sleep` right after request of cancellation. Even with sleep for 3 seconds this test sometimes fails (found after 20-ish runs), and when it passes, that long waiting is usually unnecessary (I guess). For reference, please see [diff](https://github.com/DominikJaniec/JustProblems/commit/28ed1c8ccba75bd436f4a0d76a7c08d0a28bc47a).

"Other problem", was to ensure that cancellation comes from "waiting time" and not from `Task.Run`, because `ThreadPool` could be busy (other executing tests), and it cold postpone start of second task after request of cancellation - that would render this test "falsy-green". The "easy fix by hack" was to actively wait until second task starts - its `Status` becomes `TaskStatus.Running`. Please check version under this [branch](https://github.com/DominikJaniec/JustProblems/tree/TaskCancellation/bug-passes-test) and see that test without this hack will be sometimes "green" - so exampled bug could pass through it.

Comment: I'm looking for solution, for green tests when nothing was changes in the system. I'm not sure if this test is good at all, or even necessary for our system, as passed actions should also do the check over token. I think we could drop it, but this is more like challenge for me now. Also, I'would like to see this test without any sleeps or hacks. Nevertheless, implementation of `LimitingExecutor` could also be better - no need to take task from the pool and then freeze it on semaphore, maybe some active waiting with shared counter and `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Why don't you use a custom TaskScheduler or better yet, [an ActionBlock<T> with a limited DOP instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-a-dataflow-block) ? An ActionBlock [already supports cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-dataflow-block).

Comment: What you ask is already supported by the TPL through custom TaskScheduler classes and factories. Check [this example of a LimitingTaskScheduler](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Execution-Time-Based-dd4dbdb6/sourcecode?fileId=67470&pathId=1378361369). It can be used to create a new TaskFactory whose tasks use that specific TaskScheduler.

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos for pointing me at _TPL Dataflow Library_, as previously I haven't got occasion to take closer look at this library, it looks very interesting. However, my (real) problem is not directly related to transforming data and binding multiple asynchronous processes in to _the flow_. It is more like scheduler, which needs only to prevent too many action to be started (and then executed) at once. Nevertheless, I don't feel that implementing whole `TaskScheduler` is right direction or would be accepted as solution in my team - it feels over-complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test method assumes that `cancellingTask` always takes the slot (enters the semaphore) in `LimitingExecutor` before the `actionTask`. Unfortunatelly, this assumption is wrong, `LimitingExecutor` does not guarantee this and it's just a matter of luck, which of the two task takes the slot (actually on my computer it only happens in something like 5% of runs).

To resolve this problem, you need another `ManualResetEvent`, that will allow main thread to wait until `cancellingTask` actually occupies the slot:

```
using (var slotTaken = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false))
using (var setupEvent = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false))
using (var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource())
using (var executor = new LimitingExecutor())
{
    // System-state setup action:
    var cancellingTask = executor.Do(() =>
    {
        // This is called from inside the semaphore, so it's
        // certain that this task occupies the only available slot.
        slotTaken.Set();

        setupEvent.WaitOne();
        cancellation.Cancel();
    }, CancellationToken.None);

    // Wait until cancellingTask takes the slot
    slotTaken.WaitOne();

    // Now it's guaranteed that cancellingTask takes the slot, not the actionTask

    // ...
}
```

*.NET Framework* doesn't provide API to detect task transition to the `Running` state, so if you don't like polling the `State` property + `Thread.Sleep()` in a loop, you'll need to modify `LimitingExecutor.Do()` to provide this information, probably using another `ManualResetEvent`, e.g.:

```
public Task Do(Action work, CancellationToken token, ManualResetEvent taskRunEvent = null)
    => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Optional notification to the caller that task is now running
        taskRunEvent?.Set();

        // ...
    }, token);
```

Comment: Thank you Ňuf :) It's true that concurrent programming is hard. Thank you very much for pointing me at this (seeming now) obvious problem: that those tasks will not start necessary in requested order. So, to answer my question, here we do not observe any _propagation-time-issues_ of requested cancellation in TPL. Further, I can assume that cancellation will be instantly (from .NET perspective) observable from any interested task, after time when `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` method returns. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In case of my way of active waiting for `actionTask`, I do not think it's very bad, however it is pitty that there is no API for that case - but, maybe nobody needs that in real life other then tests, as I'm never see that needs before. Thank you for suggestion about `ManualResetEvent` in `Do` method. It looks like good idea and I would probably accommodated it, but I feel that changing "production" code only for tests is not the best practise - so I will leave it as it is now.